# Does FileVault technically require SIP?

Tags: filevault, sip

To disable SIP I must disable FileVault. Is there a technical reason that FileVault needs SIP?

IIRC I had FileVault enabled and SIP disabled on older versions of OSX.

Comment: Which version of macOS are you using, on which hardware?

Comment: Generic answer, please.

Comment: A generic answer isn't possible, due to differences in hardware and macOS versions.

Comment: Then explain the divisions.

Comment: Apple does not mention the need to disable Filevault in order to disable SIP. What makes you think that is the case? Also, this sounds like an X-Y question. What are you trying to achieve, overall?

Comment: You may be right, I might be confused, there are a lot of terms. What I'm trying to do is irrelevant to the question, I'm interested in the answer (or if my assumption is wrong, that.) Don't answer the question you want to answer, answer the question asked.

Comment: Also, and I shouldn't need to add this, if you don't know the answer, it's OK not to post.

Comment: The more information you give, the better and more useful the answer to you and everyone else who reads it. If you're not inclined to do that, then you'll find people aren't inclined to help you with your problem.

Comment: No, it will invite a specific answer to a question I haven't asked, and am not interested in.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I was not aware of that, no. `csrutil status` still says SIP is enabled on other versions. Is it simply wrong? Or is this about macOS vs OSX nomenclature?

Comment: Nice pedantry, but being manipulative isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer your specific question:

No, FileVault does not technically require SIP. At all.

Comment: Thanks.

Seems like there is an answer after all, and that my question doesn't need detail. Heaven forbid I should actually be able to ask the question I have.

Comment: Well, I think people are trying to tell you two things: 1) Disabling SIP usually (i.e. really never) requires disabling FileVault. So the premise for your question is “muddy” - either it is completely wrong, or you should really share some information on this special case, you have found. 2) That getting the question answered won’t help you in any practical sense. You won’t get SIP disabled without disabling FileVault that way. However plenty of people know exactly how to do that, so if you asked that, they would be happy to answer.

Comment: Honestly, A) thanks for engaging in good faith, and B) I disagree, I genuinely thought there was a FV/SIP issue, but there wasn't. I was confusing SIP for SVV, I think. So, in answering the question directly, you have helped me past my confusion. And, you've left a good record of fact for other people with the same question, whether they have arrived at it from naivety or confusion.